# SQL Monitoring Window

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I tried to use real time sql monitoring tool, but once I started, all the tools bar at the top of the window are grayed out, and once I run the sql query, nothing happens in the monitor window.

The tool is **Oracle Enterprise Manager.**

Do you know how to make it work or need some special permission?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: which tool? please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Which tool are you talking about?

Comment: @Simonare sorry I forgot to add it. I edited my question now.

Comment: Thanky you @APC

Answer (score 2):

The Real Time SQL Monitoring tool in Oracle Enterprise Manager (or SQL Developer) requires Enterprise Edition and the Diagnostics and Tuning options (chargeable extras to the EE license). [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm#DBLIC159).

Are you connecting as a SYSDBA account? If not, that might account for the menu items being disabled. However, you should check that your organisation  has the necessary licenses before using this feature.

Comment: that stuff is there whether the licenses are or not, i think it's more likely to be user priv issue with the views/packages

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - as you seem to know a bit more about it maybe you should post an answer :D

Comment: well, i never use EM, but...  :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your database user has privileges on data dictionary views like:

- gv$active_session_history
- gv$sql_monitor
- gv$sql_monitor
- gv$sql_plan_monitor

([DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/tgsql/monitoring-database-operations.html#GUID-5D853CB9-D65C-44DF-BB43-058DA861B42D))

If you're still having issues with EM, then SQL Developer also has an interface for RTSM on the Tools Menu:

[image]